# Read a View created from a procedure in SAP HANA from R

Tags: r, jdbc, hana, dbconnection, rjdbc

I have schema in SAP HANA by the name **"HYZ_ProcurementToSales"** and View **"V_HYZ_P25_Market_Market_Orders"** which is created from a procedure, I am trying to extract the view in the R server version 1.0.153. The code I am using is:

```
library(RJDBC)
conn_server <- dbConnect(jdbcDriver,
"jdbc:sap:rdkom12.dhcp.pal.sap.corp:30015", "system",
"manager")
res <- dbGetQuery(conn,"select * from 
HYZ_ProcurementToSales.V_HYZ_P25_Market_Market_Orders")
```

The error that I get is this:

```
"Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for 
select * from HYZ_ProcurementToSales.V_HYZ_P25_Market_Market_Orders".
```

My belief is that something else instead of dbGetQuery will do the trick here. It works fine if I simply do

```
res <- dbGetQuery(conn,"select * from Tables")
```

Comment: Please add your code for the procedure as well, so that we can understand the options for reading the data.

Comment: @LarsBr., I have updated the code, my objective is to create a data frame from the view.

Comment: @LarsBr., The error that I get when I run the second last command with res variable is "Unable to retrieve the JDBC result set for select * Schema.View_Name.

Comment: @LarsBr., kindly suggest some possible approach as I have updated the post as you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me on HANA 1 SPS12 with a procedure that exposes a view called `V_CURRENTUSERS`:

```
library(RJDBC)
drv <- JDBC("com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver",
            "C:\\Program Files\\SAP\\hdbclient\\ngdbc.jar",
            identifier.quote='"')
conn <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:sap://<hanaserver>:3<instance>15/?", "**username**", "*pw*")

jusers <- dbFetch(dbSendQuery(conn = conn, statement = 'select * from v_currentusers;'))
```

At this point, the whole result set is bound to `jusers`.
Once finished you should release the result set again:

```
dbClearResult(jusers)
```

and finally close the connection

```
dbDisconnect(conn)
```

Be aware that procedures with result views are deprecated and should not be used/developed anymore. Instead, use table functions as these can also be reused in information views and allow for dynamic parameter assignment.

Comment: in the jusers statement, if the view v_currentusers belongs to a schema, how do you mention the schema name along with the view. I am still getting an error, "unable to find inherited method for function 'dbSendQuery' for signature". Please help.

Comment: This error is unrelated to the schema. To specify the schema, you use the standard notation e.g. `'select * from "DEVDUDE"."V_CURRENTUSERS";'`.  The error you're facing seems more related to the installation of `RJDBC` and the dependent packages. Are you sure they are all installed correctly?

Comment: I will be very honest here, I am exactly trying this command, but don't no what is the issue here, the package is installed rightly here. Actually I am on the citrix environment using windows VM.

Comment: Well, it's a different error than the one in your question now, isn't it? Can you please post the current code and all the current output? Also, can you verify the R version that you're using? I tested with the R version 3.3.1. Type in `version` and include the output in your question.

Comment: The code is absolutely correct as above and I am using here R studio server version 1.0.153.

Comment: That's an ancient version. In fact it would set your R installation into the year 2000. rJDBC requires R >=2.4. Since it apparently loaded OK, I've got to assume, you reported the version number of something different. Mind posting the output of `version` as I asked?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160083/discussion-between-ashmin-kaul-and-lars-br).

Comment: I have figured the solution, your code also helped me in the process, I appreciate it greatly, Thanks for the help.

Comment: So, what was the actual solution? Anyone who reads that surely would like to know.

Comment: The select comment you mentioned above, just the colon ";" at the end is not needed. Thanks a lot.